# Delete file without playing sound in Applescript?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

```
tell application "Finder"
    set deletedfile to alias "Snow Leopard:Users:test.pdf"
    delete deletedfile
end tell
```

The problem is I repeatedly call this script from my Cocoa application so the sound is played repeatedly too. Is it possible to disable that sound ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the trash is just an invisible folder inside your home folder you can do this...

```
set myFile to (path to desktop folder as text) & "myFile.txt"
set trashFolder to path to trash folder from user domain

do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of myFile & space & quoted form of POSIX path of trashFolder
```

Answer (score -1):

one simple way (doesn't move to Trash)

```
do shell script "rm '/Users/test.pdf'"
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I need to delete to trash